# Filtering Collection on Boolean property not working

Tags: asp.net, linq, ado.net

I want to filter my list on one of the class property `isactive`. But it is not filtering correctly it is showing all the item. Below is the code.

```
Roaster_Driver[] drivers = null;
drivers = client.GetDriverDetail();
List<Roaster_Driver> drvrs = drivers.Where(x => x.isactive = true).ToList();
```

It showing all the items in the `drvrs` even there are some inactive item in `drivers`. When I debug the program and apply third LINQ Statement all the boolean statuses in the `drivers` get updated by `True`. I tried below alternative too but not worked for me.

```
 var drvrs = (from driver in drivers
                     where driver.isactive = true
                     select driver);
```

What is missing in my code or any changes required please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison in C# done via `==` operator, not single `=` (which is assignment).

```
List<Roaster_Driver> drvrs = drivers.Where(x => x.isactive == true).ToList();
```

Also you don't need to compare boolean values with `true` or `false` - use values directly:

```
List<Roaster_Driver> drvrs = drivers.Where(x => x.isactive).ToList();
```

Query syntax:

```
var drvrs = from driver in drivers
            where driver.isactive
            select driver;
```

Comment: Its working for me. Why it is updating original collection. Can you assist?

Comment: @eraj sorry, was afk. It should not update original collection, because its just query, which *filters* original collection

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `==` instead of `=` for comparison

```
List<Roaster_Driver> drvrs = drivers.Where(x => x.isactive == true).ToList();
```

or

```
List<Roaster_Driver> drvrs = drivers.Where(x => x.isactive).ToList();
```